# Как подключить qtserialport если используется статическая версия Qt?

Tags: qt, qt5

Доброго времени суток.
Есть комплект QT 5.4 со статической линковкой библиотек.
Отдельно собрал qtserialport. Подскажите, как теперь добавить эту библиотеку в проект стандартным способом - через .pro файл?

```
QT       += core serialport
```

Можно конечно подключить вручную через LIBS += & INCLUDEPATH += , но это не вариант, т.к. в режиме отладки нужна одна версия библиотеки, а в режиме release другая.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я делал так

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    SUFFIX_STR = _g
}
else {
    SUFFIX_STR = 
}
LIBS += -lserialport$${SUFFIX_STR}
```

Можно соответственно использовать похожую конструкцию

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    LIBS += -lserialport1
    INCLUDEPATH += serialport1.h
}
else {
    LIBS += -lserialport2
    INCLUDEPATH += serialport2.h
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это мне наверняка пригодится. Оказалось, что я забыл скопировать qt_lib_serialport.pri в папку с комплектом, в итоге qmake не мог найти модуль serialport.

Answer (score 2):

Собрать его статически вместе со всем Qt.